# MongoDB oid in mysql

Tags: mysql, mongodb, performance

Let's say I have a collection of documents in MongoDb. Each has different labels. The label names are stored in MySQL and I want to have a relations table "doc-label", because every document can have many labels and every label may appear on many documents.
What would be the best way to refer to the mongo documents? Storing the OID as a string in the MySQL table would result in a pretty slow query:

```
SELECT  *
    FROM `LABEL`
    INNER JOIN `DOC_LABEL` ON LABEL.id = DOC_LABEL.label_id
    INNER JOIN `DOC` ON DOC.id = DOC_LABEL.doc_id
    WHERE  DOC.id = '507f1f77bcf86cd799439011'
```

Comment: That query is invalid -- There is no table `DOC`.  Please fix.

Comment: Not sure there's a "best" way. But... perhaps consider storing labels within the documents in MongoDB (even if you retain MySQL for the "system of truth" for all labels)? Seems like you're forcing an inefficient jump between database systems to resolve labels. Why not just denormalize a bit, and store your labels in the documents, to prevent extra reads & latency? And you'd also be able to index and search based on labels as well.

Comment: @RickJames - fixed. Thanks for pointing that out.

Comment: @DavidMakogon - I guess you are right about the approach. Though, technically I still think there is probably a way out there to store OID efficiently in MySQL.

Comment: Is `507f1f77bcf86cd799439011` an OID?  That won't slow down MySQL significantly.  Yeah, a lot of people say that strings are bad; but a BTree is a BTree.  The length of the key has very little to do with performance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @RickJames put it:

Is 507f1f77bcf86cd799439011 an OID? That won't slow down MySQL significantly. Yeah, a lot of people say that strings are bad; but a BTree is a BTree. The length of the key has very little to do with performance